# [io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory]: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc

My Java Spring Boot project fails at startup with the given error:

`Failed to instantiate [io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle-r2dbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: As of this writing, use oracle-r2dbc 0.1.0 in Spring projects.

`oracle-r2dbc` 0.4.0 depends on a newer version of `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi` than `spring-data-r2dbc` 1.4.3.

You may have to clear your build tool or IDE's cache for the change to take effect. (In my case `mvn clean` and IntelliJ "Invalidate Caches...")

Btw, when I downgraded, I think it broke using descriptors in the rdbc URL so I had to switch to a URL like this: `r2dbc:oracle://<host>:<port>/<service-name>`

Update, just saw on Oracle's driver docs for r2dbc, it says:

> Use the 0.1.0 version of Oracle R2DBC if you are programming with
> Spring. The later versions of Oracle R2DBC implement the 0.9.x
> versions of the R2DBC SPI. Currently, Spring only supports drivers
> that implement the 0.8.x versions of the SPI.

https://github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc

DO NOT USE 0.2.0 with Spring - even worse than no error, queries just hang forever. I spent over a day trying to debug it. Not only I had the wrong version, but when I actually did try changing the version, my IDE was caching the old version out of sync with Maven.