# Oracle R2DBC query hangs / never completes

Tags: oracle, spring-data-r2dbc

I am using Oracle r2dbc in my Spring Boot application.

I have a DatabaseClient set up and when I call:

`databaseClient.sql("select ...").fetch().one().block();`

The function never returns. It just hangs forever. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when using an incompatible version of `com.oracle.database.r2dbc:oracle-r2dbc`.

> Use the 0.1.0 version of Oracle R2DBC if you are programming with
> Spring. The later versions of Oracle R2DBC implement the 0.9.x
> versions of the R2DBC SPI. Currently, Spring only supports drivers
> that implement the 0.8.x versions of the SPI.

https://github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc

Be sure to use 0.1.0 and NOT 0.2.0.  (Versions 0.3.0 and later will give [obscure errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71710673/) instead of hanging.)

After updating the dependencies in your build system, you may have to invalidate / clear your IDE's cache as well. For Intellij/Maven users, I think the "Reload all Maven projects" button might work too.